# Moose attribute coercion - MooseX::Types::URI

Tags: perl, moose

The synopsis for [MooseX::Types::URI](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?MooseX::Types::URI) says:

> use MooseX::Types::URI qw(Uri FileUri DataUri);

So, my example code:

```
package My;
use 5.014;
use warnings;
use Moose;
use MooseX::Types::URI qw(Uri);

has 'url' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => 'Maybe[Uri]',
    coerce => 1,
);

package main;
my $m0 = My->new(); #without url - ok
```

Error:

> You cannot coerce an attribute (url) unless its type (Maybe[Uri]) has
>   a coercion at ./maybe line 9.

With:

```
my $m1 = My->new( url => 'http://example.com' );
```

different error:

> You cannot coerce an attribute (url) unless its type (Maybe[Uri]) has
>     a coercion at ./maybe line 9.
>     Attribute (url) does not pass the type
>     constraint because: Validation failed for 'Maybe[Uri]' with value
>     http://example.com at

---

Ok, so next try - without `''`:

```
has 'url' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => Maybe[Uri],
    coerce => 1,
);
```

Error:

> ```
> syntax error at ./maybe line 11, near "Maybe["
> Execution of ./maybe aborted due to compilation errors.
> ```

---

Another *try*, added the `use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( Maybe );` :

```
use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( Maybe );
use MooseX::Types::URI qw(Uri);

has 'url' => (
    is => 'rw',
    isa => Maybe[Uri],
    coerce => 1,
);

...
my $m1 = My->new( url => 'http://example.com' );
```

> You cannot coerce an attribute (url) unless its type
>   (Maybe[MooseX::Types::URI::Uri]) has a coercion at ./maybe line 9.
>
> Attribute (url) does not pass the type constraint because: Validation
>   failed for 'Maybe[MooseX::Types::URI::Uri]' with value
>   http://example.com at

Don't works anything. Don't want anymore  more *tryings*, what are unsuccessful at all.

I really want **LEARN** how to decide how to use the *already developed* CPAN defined MooseX Types, when to use the `''` and when not, and how the above will works...

Could **please** someone explain me, what I'm doing wrong? What I missed from from any doccu, especially from:

- [Moose::Manual::Types](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Manual::Types)
- [Moose::Util::TypeConstraints](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose::Util::TypeConstraints#Type_Constraint_Constructors) (e.g.: "It is **always** a good idea to quote your type names.")

or what else should I read?

An hopeless Moose beginner... ;(

## Edit

My question is based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20134993/1515483) answer (and others too), where - for example:

```
use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( ArrayRef );
use MooseX::Types::Path::Class qw( Dir );

has 'volumes' => (
    is => 'ro',
    isa => ArrayRef[Dir],
    required => 1,
    coerce => 1,
);
```

The bareword "syntax" is a must. I only changed the `ArrayRef` to `Maybe` and `Dir` to `Uri`.

So, the main question remains, how an ordinary perl beginner can decide when *can/must* use the "bareword" syntax and when the "string"-syntax?

Why the `ArrayRef[Dir]` is valid (and must) and the `Maybe[Uri]` not? Why such inconsistency? To understand this, i must study the sources for Moose*? HOW TO understand this? What I should READ?

Comment: Re your update: `ArrayRef[Dir]`, when you have a sub named `ArrayRef` and a sub named `Dir`, is short for `ArrayRef( [ Dir() ] )`. You can only call a sub named `ArrayRef` if you have a sub named `ArrayRef`. You know you have a sub named that when you declare it or you use a module that provides it. The whole point of `MooseX::Types::Moose` is to create functions that return their own name.

Comment: As for why `use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( Maybe );` doesn't provide `Maybe`? Well, it does for me. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could please someone explain me, what I'm doing wrong?

Nothing. Like the message says, there's no rule defining how to coerce a `Str` to `Maybe[Uri]`. You'd have to define one.

That said, I don't know if that's possible. The alternative is to use

```
'Undef|Uri'
```

instead of

```
'Maybe[Uri]'
```

---

> Ok, so next try - without `''`

`Maybe[...]` is simply not valid Perl syntax.

> Another try, added the `use MooseX::Types::Moose qw( Maybe );`

Actually, this works for me (i.e. gives the coercion error rather than a syntax error). As it should, it creates a function that returns the string `Maybe[Uri]` when passed a reference to an array containing the string `Uri` (`Maybe( [ Uri() ] )` aka `Maybe[Uri]`).

---

> I really want LEARN how to decide how to use the already developed CPAN defined MooseX Types, when to use the '' and when not, and how the above will works...

You have to provide a string that's the name of a type. Usually that done using a string literal (e.g. `'Str'`), but any expression will do (e.g. `chr(53).chr(74).chr(72)`).

---

Notes:

1. I once provide a patch to add coercion support to `Maybe`, but it was rejected because they don't like `Maybe`. (At least, that's what they told me.)

Comment: As usually, your answer is correct and works. ;) Thank you. But, please, read my EDIT - and if it is possible, extend your answer.

Comment: Giving up. Probably will never understand this. For you it works, for me gives and error. Simply, will remember - don't use `Maybe`, the 'Undef|something' works. ;)  Thank you for help anyway. ;)

Comment: Of course it gives an error. I explicitly said it does, and I explained the error. If you're getting the *syntax* error, then maybe you're using an old version of the module?

Comment: FWIW, in Types::Standard coercions for `Maybe[Uri]` Just Work™. :-)

Comment: @tobyink thank for pointing me to `Types::Standard`. Simply, have problem finding the "most recommended" or "best valued" modules in CPAN. Havent idea how effectively search. This looks really good. thanx :)